# function call itself fails to return unique values

Tags: vb.net

What am i doing wrong here. function keeps returning "0001". while i debug it step by step, i figured this line generateNo gets executed again after End function. why is that so?

```
public class form 1
    Dim invCount As integer = 1
End class

 Public Function generateInvNo() As String

    Dim invString As String
    'format invString

    If (invCount < 10) Then
        invString = "000" + invCount.ToString
    ElseIf (invCount > 10 And invCount < 100) Then
        invString = "00" + invCount.ToString
    ElseIf (invCount > 100 And invCount < 1000) Then
        invString = "0" + invCount.ToString
    Else
        invString = invCount.ToString

    End If
    'check database to see if invString already exist

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    conn = accessDB.opendatabase
    conn.Open()
    Dim dbString As String = "SELECT InvoiceNo FROM INVOICE WHERE InvoiceNo = '" & invString & "' "
    Dim dbStringCommand As New OleDbCommand(dbString, conn)
    Dim dbReader As OleDbDataReader = dbStringCommand.ExecuteReader
    If dbReader.Read Then
        'means invoiceNo exist.
        invCount += 1
        generateInvNo() 'error at here: this line executes again after End function
    Else

        Return invString
    End If
    Return 0

End Function
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking -- are you saying that some line of code from inside the Function is getting executed After you have reached `End Function`?

Comment: yes willman. that surprises me

Comment: FYI use String.PadLeft to generate a string with the correct number of 0s. invCount.ToString().PadLeft(4, "0") will give you the 0001 or 0100 format

Comment: FriendlyManCub.. wow that's brilliant! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring other issues, get rid of that final `Return 0` and change `generateInvNo()` to `Return generateInvNo()`.  You have the function calling itself and then ignoring the value returned by that recursive call and just returning 0.  How can that be what you intended?

Comment: tnx jmcilhinney.  hope you don't mind me asking why  Return generateInvNo() worked?